# Save any image to MySQL as Blob

Tags: java, mysql, blob

I have this codes to save image in MySQL but it doesn't work.

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
MyDB.con.setAutoCommit(false);
File pic = new File(txtPicPath.getText().trim());
fis = new FileInputStream(pic);
ps = MyDB.con.prepareStatement("insert into `photo`(`Employee ID`, Picture) values (?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, Data.User.getText());
ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, pic.length());
ps.executeUpdate();
MyDB.con.commit();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Upload Successfully");
btnPicdelete.setEnabled(true);
btnBrowse.setEnabled(false);
btnUpload.setEnabled(false);
txtPicPass.setText("");    
txtPicPath.setText("");
```

The problem is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: image1.jpg (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

The image name I upload is `image1.jpg`.

Comment: Error clearly says `System cannot find the file specified`. Are you sure you have image1.jpg in the specified path?

Comment: check whether the image path is correct, or you have put file in correct directory.

Comment: Specify the complete path of the file. Also check if its is present.

Comment: Yes it is cause I use JFileChooser() to get that @PradeepSimha

Comment: the image is located at the desktop @ay89

Comment: @kelvzy u have given absolute path or relative? if relative u sure u r running the app from desktop itself if image is at desktop?

Answer (score 0):

U need to specify complete path to the image in your jTextField or u can use `getClass().getResource()` as an alternative !

Example:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("../Image/pyPic.jpg");  
                InputStream is = url.openStream();
```

Comment: but now how can I fix that image into the width or size of my jlabel? @c.pramod

Answer (score 0):

My filename must be:

```
txtPicPath.setText(file.getAbsoluteFile().toString())
```